# UIViewController in UITabBarController is Black

Tags: uitableview, uiviewcontroller, delegates, uitabbarcontroller

I have a `UITabBarController` with 3 tabs. One of the `UIViewControllers`, which controls one of the tabs, is a `UITableViewDelegate` and has an embedded `UITableView` which uses a portion of the screen. There are some buttons that appear below the `UITableView`.

This `UIViewController` generally works, but if I make changes to the code (could be in any file), sometimes this `UIViewController` will display nothing but black between the `Navigation Bar` and the `Tab Bar`. I can switch to other tabs and they act as expected.

Even stranger, if I go to the `Storyboard` and change the order of the tabs, then the problematic `UIViewController` starts working again. All I am doing is changing the order of the tabs ...

Any ideas about what is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert on swift, but I've spent lots of time with tab bars and UITableViews inside of UIViewControllers. Here are things that I would check/do:

- reset my simulator (run it, and use the simulator menus)
- clean my build area
- change the table view background color to red
- change the table view tintColor to green
- change the outermost view background color to yellow
- change the outermost view tintColor to blue
- now when it goes black, maybe it will show another color
- check, and double check the constraints on the table view
- the blackness might be caused by no cells getting displayed, or by the whole table view losing its sizes somehow